# sql show date time as dd/mm/yy hh:mm:ss without using CONVERT(VARCHAR(10)

Tags: sql, date, formatting, ingres

I am using Ingres Db  which is old and cant do much,
I need to show datetime in specific format  as

> dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss

DB  retunrn me it as

> 01.02.2018 14:43:53

it is **NOT SQL server** so I CANNOT use CONVERT(VARCHAR(10)
Is there a way  to convert it to format i need ?

Comment: Where do you want to show the information? In a particular application?

Comment: @PedroMartins it  will go directly to excel, but  i cant  modify it in excel

Comment: Have you seen this? https://communities.actian.com/s/article/Working-with-Ingresdate-Date-Fields It refers a few functions like date_part

Comment: @PedroMartins I saw it, its not  working properly  insted of  adres its return me some randome number

Comment: Have you tried altering your II_DATE_FORMAT setting? (Use "ingprenv" to see what it's set to). In recent versions of Ingres you can also alter this display format within your SQL session using "set date_format 'name';", see docs for available date format names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to show it as dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss you have to do next

> ```
> SELECT Varchar(Date_part('day', date('now')))
>        + '-'
>        + Varchar(Date_part('month', date('now')))
>        + '-'
>        + Varchar(Date_part('year', date('now')))
>        + ' '
>        + Varchar(Date_part('hour', date('now')))
>        + ':'
>        + Varchar(Date_part('minute', date('now')))
>        + ':'
>        + Varchar(Date_part('second', date('now')));
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Use Replace
 `select REPLACE('01.02.2018 14:43:53','.','-')`

Comment: Please add some explenation to your answer.

Comment: @vivek kumar , your solution will only  work if date saved as string! Because you cannot use replace cannot work wit ingresdate format